# Solving dispersion equation

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the dispersion equation:

`w^2 = k*g * tanh(kh)`

I have a vector (25x1 element) input for w and want a vector output for k.
I've tried below, but is highly dependent on the tolerance values for uniroot.all:

```r
g = 9.81        #m/s^2

h = 8        #m

w = c(0.1,0.2,0.3) # 3 element vector for ease

dispersion <- function(k) { 0 == k*g*tanh(k*h)^0.5-w }

k1 <- uniroot.all(function(k) dispersion(1e4), c(-10,10), tol = 1e-100, maxiter = 1000)
```

Comment: please clarify what your question is

Comment: How do I solve the equation for k with a vector input of w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an apply function, like so:

```r
# Parameters
g <- 9.81
h <- 8
w <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

# Function to find root of
disp_root <- function(k, w) {k * g * tanh(k * h) - w^2 }

# Apply for each w
res <- sapply(w, function(x)rootSolve::uniroot.all(disp_root, c(-1,1), w = x))

# Repackage results
df_res <- data.frame(w, t(res))

# Fix names
names(df_res)[2:3] <- c("first_root", "second_root")

# Examine results
df_res
#>     w  first_root second_root
#> 1 0.1 -0.01126658  0.01126658
#> 2 0.2 -0.02272161  0.02272161
#> 3 0.3 -0.03419646  0.03419646
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. for completeness it would be  (k * g * tanh(k * h))^0.5 - w